# Producer Consumer pattern - handling producer failure

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a producer/consumer pattern like the following

- A fixed number of producer threads, each writing on to their own BlockingQueue, invoked via an Executor
- A single consumer thread, reading off the producer threads

Each producer is running a database query and writing the results to its Queue. The consumer polls all the producer Queues. At the moment if there is a database error the producer thread dies and then the consumer gets stuck forever waiting for more results on the product Queue.

How should I be structuring this to handle catch errors correctly?

Comment: Use future.get() inside a try/catch?

Answer (score 4):

I once did a similar thing and decided to use a sentinel value that the dying producer thread would push into the queue from the catch-block. You can push the exception itself (this works in most scenarios), or have a special object for that. In any case it is great to push the exception to the consumer for debugging purposes.

Comment: That is the correct approach. Push an instance of 'whatever it is' with appropriate error data - the exception object, whatever.  It's easier if the class that usually carries the data has success/fail/error members so that the data that caused the error is sent to the consumer as well.  The consumer could forward the instance to a logger and/or GUI that could then textify the exception and all the source data that generated it.

Comment: If a container object is used for all queue items, then a special implementation of that can be made that will rethrow the exception upon any invocation of its methods. That makes the code really simple if it is acceptable from other standpoints.

Comment: I am already doing something similar for detecting when a producer has finished producing (poison pill) so maybe I can extend that to handle this, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the only option you have when a producer dies is to stop the consumer.

To do this you can use a poison pill. This is a special object which the producer adds when it stops and the consumer knows to stop when it receives it. The poison pill can be added into a `finally` block so it is always added no matter how the producer is killed/dies.

Given you have only one consumer, I would use one queue.  This way your consumer will only block where all the producers have died.

Comment: The queues have to be kept separate due to the nature of the data coming back from the producers. I actually peek the data using a custom queue wrapper around a BlockingQueue and collate appropriately.

Comment: Is there a reason the producers cannot do the collation?

Comment: Each producing thread is a DB query in order, then the consumer has to inspect the first item off each Queue and sort them into order. So for example one queue might be producing items well before another in which many items would need to be processed off the first before starting to consume the second.

Comment: In that case the consumer cannot progress if any producer dies as they are interdependant. (You could still do as I suggested but it wouldn't help)

Comment: Yes that's true, see my answer for how I solved it, appreciate any feedback.

Comment: One advantage of the poison pill is that all the valid data collected will still be processed. The consumer only stops when it has to.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever class it is that you actually push onto the queue/s, it should contain success/fail/error members so that the consumer/s can check for fails.

Peter has already suggested using only one queue - I don't see how avoiding all that polling should be any particular problem - the objects on the queue can have members that identify which producer they came from, and any other metadata, if required.

Comment: The items are produced in a particular order so mixing the items doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

I used the following class. It takes a list of Runnable and executes them all in parallel, if one fails, it interrupts all the others. Then I have interrupt handling in my producers and consumers to die gracefully when interrupted.

This works nicely for my case.

Thanks for all the comments/answers as they gave me some ideas.

```
// helper class that does the following
//
// if any thread has an exception then interrupt all the others with an eye to cancelling them
// if the thread calling execute() is interrupted then interrupt all the child threads
public class LinkedExecutor
{
    private final Collection<Runnable> runnables;
    private final String name;

    public LinkedExecutor( String name, Collection<Runnable> runnables )
    {
        this.runnables = runnables;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool( ConfigurableThreadFactory.newWithPrefix( name ) );

        // use a completion service to poll the results
        CompletionService<Object> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Object>( executorService );

        for ( Runnable runnable : runnables )
        {
            completionService.submit( runnable, null );
        }

        try
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < runnables.size(); i++ )
            {
                Future<?> future = completionService.take();
                future.get();
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            // on an interruption of this thread interrupt all sub-threads in the executor
            executorService.shutdownNow();

            throw new RuntimeException( "Executor '" + name + "' interrupted", e );
        }
        catch ( ExecutionException e )
        {
            // on a failure of any of the sub-threads interrupt all the threads
            executorService.shutdownNow();

            throw new RuntimeException( "Execution execution in executor '" + name + "'", e );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add some timeout to kill the consumer when there are no more elements in the queue(s) for a certain time.

Another approach might be to have the producers maintain an "alive" flag and signal that they are dying by setting it to false. If the producers run continuously but might not always get results from the database the "alive" flag could be the time the producer reported to be alive the last time and then use the timeout to check whether the producer might have died (when the last report of being alive was too long ago).